# App doesn't format elements at all & just shows them all in one line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio and decided to try it out, never programmed in Java, or any kind of android app. It all seems good but once I emulated the app. I got weird formatting that wasn't a thing in app preview when I coded it. This is a simple "squaring" function app.

When I look at the preview:

[image]

When I emulate it:

[image]

Comment: Share you xml layout, we need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this kind of formatting because you are using `Constraint Layout` as your root layout. There are no constraints to the views(`EditText`, `Button` and others) because of which they are placed at the top left corner of the screen.You have to add constraints in `ContraintLayout`.

Follow any of the three methods below-

- Learn about `Constraint Layout`. Check out this link -Build a Responsive UI with [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) in Android Studio (Most Useful of the three)
- Change `Constraint Layout` to `Linear Layout` or `Relative Layout` as your root layout.(if you are familiar with them)
- Click *Infer Constraints* (orange color two stars type symbol ) to automatically create constraints and compile again.(Simplest of the 3 methods for you right now)